# Convert a Database retrieved byte array to an image in Razor View MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, blob

**image with**

```
src="data:image;base64,YmxvYjpodHRwJTNBLy9sb2NhbGhvc3QlM0ExNDE0MS8wMzI1ZTA3Mi1iOTA5LTQ0YjItOTVlNS1iYzc4ZmJhZTZhMzI=" attribute value isn't displayed
with database table that has just one record with id=1
```

**Razor**

```
<img id="BlobPic" src="data:image;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Logoo)" style="max-width:90%;" />
```

**Action method**

```
public FileContentResult getImg(int id)
        {
            BladiaInfoViewModel Bladia_Logo = rep.getByID(Convert.ToDecimal(1));
            byte[] byteArray = Bladia_Logo.Logoo;
            return new FileContentResult(Bladia_Logo.Logoo, "image/jpeg");
        }
```

**Jquery**

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("getImg")',
                data: { 'id': "1" },
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    //document.getElementById("BlobPic").src = "data:image/png;base64," + data.Logoo;
                    document.getElementById("Logo").setAttribute("src",'@Url.Action("getImg", "BaldiaInfo",
                    new { id = Model.Logoo})');

                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("try again");
                }
            });
            //----
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're returning a `FileContentResult` then it looks like you're *really* overcomplicating this.  Presumably you have a page in which the model which populates that page includes an identifier used by this action, right?:

```
public FileContentResult getImg(int id)
```

If so then you don't need all of this AJAX or Base64-encoding data URIs or anything like that.  All you need to do is reference the URL with the ID.  Something like this:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("getImg", "BaldiaInfo",
                new { id = Model.Logoo})" />
```

This would create the URL for that action:

```
<img src="/BaldiaInfo/getImg/123" />
```

And since that action returns an image file, the browser would get exactly what it expects in that `img src`, an image.

---

Conversely, if your model for the page's view doesn't contain an ID but instead contains *the actual image data* then you don't need a separate action for getting the image at all.  Because you already have it.  In that case you can use a Base64-encoded URI directly in the model:

```
<img src="data:image;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Logoo)" />
```

No JavaScript, no separate action with a `FileContentResult`, none of that.

---

Basically, you either have an ID which you use to reference the other action **or** you have the data which you use to build a data URI.  It seems like you're trying to do both at the same time.

Comment: First of all thank you for you answer,
 the second thing is that I have one table about meta data of an institution and the image is just one field in one cell inside one table with just one row and its datatype is Blob 
so I just need to display the image returned from the database

Comment: @Asp.NetDeveloper: If the image data is included in the original data which populates the page then the latter half of this answer applies.  There would be no need for a separate action to fetch the image since the view already *has* the image.  You'd just include it in a data URI as demonstrated.

Comment: sir @David I am annoying you but you became near, I used this solution but it doesn't work. When I browse and select the image in client side by inspecting the element the src="blob:http%3A//localhost%3A14141/b47fe875-a7a2-4b17-99cd-71274655082b"
and after saving it and it returns this src="data:image;base64,YmxvYjpodHRwJTNBLy9sb2NhbGhvc3QlM0ExNDE0MS8yMTUyNDQzNC1jYjMzLTQ1ZTctOTQ0My0wYmY3ZjVlYTQyODM="

and the byte array returns this using breakpoint (web picture via link)
http://postimg.org/image/78prx7zln/

Comment: @Asp.NetDeveloper: Well, if the image data you're getting from the database (or whatever data store you're using) is only 68 bytes, then it's only 68 bytes.  That has nothing to do with the view.  It looks like what you *expect* to be binary blob data is actually a URL.  So your data isn't what you think it is.  You'll have to correct your data (or correct your assumptions about it) in order to use that data.

Comment: Okay @David What should I do thought? :D

Comment: @Asp.NetDeveloper: You should debug your application and your data.  Nobody here can help you with that.  You're trying to display an image, but according to that previous comment you don't *have* an image.  You just have some URL.